# Adding a new field in Team foundation server

Tags: tfs, sharepoint-2010, azure-devops

I have very recently started working on Team foundation server and really have limited idea on the subject.

I have been given a problem to solve and I really dont have an idea to proceed.
We are doing a TFS-Sharepoint 2010 integration.

In dev server, the TFS is configured and is pointing to TFS_DefaultCollection database. Now, in TFS, 3 new fields have been added. It points to Field101,Field102 and Field103 columns(I dont know how these columns are created but it seems it is dynamically generated,I suppose, not sure though) of WorkItemLatest table.
Some custom stored procedure is written to insert/update the database table with sharepoint webpart. Now in the stored proc, the developer has referenced Field101,Field102 and Field103 columns.

Now comes the question of deployment this to production. In production, there is already a TFS configured. We have to make changes on top of this. But, when running the sql scripts, we found, naturally, Field101,Field102 and Field103 are not present there. So, what should be our approach which will help us address this issue? Please suggest. Also, please let me know how these 3 fields are created when 3 fields are added in TFS UI? Please help.

Comment: If you run any SQL updates against your TFS server databases then you will render your server unsuportable by MSFT. DO NOT MAKE ANY CHANGES TO THOSE DATABASES. If you have you should immediately revert to a backup made before you made any changes

Comment: Thanks. What I find is it is not possible  to migrate in bits and pieces but, we need to backup and restore the whole thing in another environment.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the WITAdmin tool to export the work item type definitions that you want to edit and mahe the changes there. You can find this fully documented on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236914.aspx